# Python - class object initialization within function

Tags: python, initialization, python-3.x

The code below works (it will eventually pull records from a database via SQL), but I am having trouble understanding why the `assert` statement in the code below works.

```
def build_row(table, cols):
    """Build a class that creates instances of specific rows"""
    class DataRow:
        """Generic data row class, specialized by surrounding function"""
        def __init__(self, data):
            """Uses data and column names to inject attributes"""
            assert len(data)==len(self.cols)
            for colname, dat in zip(self.cols, data):
                setattr(self, colname, dat)
        def __repr__(self):
            return "{0}_record({1})".format(self.table, ", ".join(["{0!r}".format(getattr(self, c)) for c in self.cols]))
    DataRow.table = table
    DataRow.cols = cols.split()
    return DataRow
```

When is the length of 'data' determined and how is it guaranteed to be the same length as 'self.cols'?  Will someone please explain this behavior?

Comment: it should be `setattr(self, colname, dat)` instead of using `data`.

Comment: you also have to add `()` to call `cols.split()` otherwise your code won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may make more sense to you if you replace the references to `self.cols` and `self.table` with `self.__class__.cols` and `self.__class__.table`.  This confusion is caused by accessing class attributes through the `self` object as if they were instance attributes, and why I don't particularly like this coding idiom. When looking at the code in `__init__`, where instance attributes are typically assigned their values, it is jarring to immediately see a statement that *reads* the value of `self.cols` - where the heck did `self.cols` get initialized?! On the other hand, if you change this assert to:

```
assert len(data)==len(self.__class__.cols)
```

then it becomes clearer that the list of data values is expected to be the same length as the defined list of columns for this instance of DataRow.  The class attribute `cols` gets initialized right after the class definition, in this statement:

```
DataRow.cols = cols.split()
```

long before any instance gets created - that's why this assert works.

The writer of this code might consider converting to the more current `namedtuple` construct.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Your answer is useful (I upvoted it), but I'm still not understanding why the constructor of an instance of DataRow is able to satisfy the 'assert' statement.  As I understand your answer, 'table' and 'cols' are attributes of the class, but not necessarily the instance.  In the 'assert' statement the length of the list 'self.cols' is being compared to the length of 'data' (type? I would guess 'list').  I understand that 'data' is now an attribute of the instance of DataRow, but I don't see where 'data' can possibly be given a length before its length is compared to self.cols.

Comment: Data is being passed in to the constructor, and is most likely a list or tuple of values.  The values in data correspond to the column names defined in cols.  A simple example would be: `DateClass=build_row('date','year month day'); today = DateClass([2011, 6, 13]); print today.year, today.month, today.day`

Comment: And no, data is *not* an attribute of the instance, it is merely an argument passed to the initializer.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Thank you for the above helpful comment. "Data is being passed in to the constructor, and is most likely a list or tuple of values." I still don't see where any assignment is being made to `data` before the `assert` statment is reached.

Comment: This is a fundamental concept, the passing of arguments to functions. Do you understand where a and b get "assigned" in this: `def add(a,b): return a+b; c = add(10,20)` When add is called, argument a gets the value 10, and argument b gets the value 20. In the DateClass example I posted, when the initializer gets called when creating `today`, argument `data` gets the value `[2011, 6, 13]`.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Yes, I get the fundamental concept of passing arguments to functions.  And I follow your `DateClass` example. But I don't actually see where an object is being bound to `data`.  For example, I am able to run the following code after running the code for `build_row`: `r = build_row('ex_table', 'col1 col2, col3'); r.table; r.cols; type(r)`.  The following are returned (respectively): 'ex_table', ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], <type 'classobj'>.  As far as I see, I never bound an object to `data`, and certainly didn't bind an object with `len` equal to `len(self.cols)`.

Comment: That is because you are never actually constructing an instance of the class returned by build_row (which you are storing in r), so you never call `__init__`, so the assert is not being run. In the DateClass example I posted, I not only defined the DateClass class, but then used it to create an instance `today`, and *that* is when `__init__` gets called, and *that* is when `data` gets passed in to be used to assign the attributes year, month, and day, and the input list `[2011, 6, 13]` gets bound to `data` in the method `__init__` and the builtin `len` is used to make sure it has 3 items.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Thank you for your patience. I see what you are saying.  In my example, `r` contains a "factory" which can create `DataRow` instances, but I haven't yet "turned on" the "factory". I can "turn on" the "factory" by passing an object to `DataRow()` which should be a tuple or list (this is checked by `assert`). Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are now getting the idea.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is given a value when you instantiate the class returned by the `build_row()` function.

It is *not* guaranteed to be the same length as `self.cols`; perhaps you never instantiate the class, and so never see an error.

Comment: What value is assigned to 'data' once the class is instantiated?  Is it of type None by default and then later assigned a value?

Comment: No. `data` is an argument of the initializer, hence it gets the value passed to the constructor.

Comment: So, when the 'init' method is called, the inclusion of 'data' as an argument simply assigns the string 'data' to the namespace of the DataRow class. Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: Arguments to a function are considered local to that function. It doesn't become part of an object until you assign to an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined `DataRow`, the column names are set in the variable `self.cols`. So, when you're instantiating the class, you're supposed to fill every column.

That's why you need both lists having the same length. Otherwise you may not have all attributes.

The way it's done is by setting an attribute with the name of the column which isn't be the best option because if you have a column named `cols` or `table` or even `__repr__`, it may break your code.

Comment: first because the code should be `cols.split()` instead of `cols.split`. Then it really works

Comment: NVM, Ignacio's answer explains it.

Comment: "When you defined DataRow, the column names are set in the variable self.cols." How does Python know to assign the column names to the variable self.cols?  Is it because the superclass of of DataRow (object) has 'cols' in its namespace because we're still within the local namespace of the function build_row?

Comment: at the very end of your code: `DataRow.cols = cols.split()` it means that when you access `self.cols` you'll get the cols name because it's now an attribute